# creating Custom FormView

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls, formview

I'm extending the formview class to create a custome formview which has a server control +formview + other server control below it.

the problem is i cant uses

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Parent.Controls.Add(FormViewButtons);
        Parent.Controls.Add(this);
        Parent.Controls.Add(MessageContainerControl);
    }
```

because i get exception: "The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.".

any Ideas?
tanks.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be creating a [Composite Custom Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479016.aspx), not extending the FormView.

Comment: tank u. when using System.Web.UI.WebControls.FromView in page we can click small arrow to edit ItemTemplate and EditItemTemplte and ... now how i can enable this feature in my composite Control.

Comment: In this method   protected virtual void CreateControlHierarchy()
   {
       TextBox t = new TextBox();
       Label l = new Label();
       t.Text = Text;
       l.Text = Title;
       Controls.Add(l);
       Controls.Add(t);
   }

Like in this sample, they are adding a TextBox and Label to the Composite Control.  This is where you would add your FormViewButtons, FormView and MessageContainerControl.

Comment: i didn't understand what did you mean. now i have my custom composite controls, composed of three controls. now all i want is to enable my composite control to show small arrow like generic FormView to edit it's item template

Comment: That's a whole different question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why should the FormView manipulate the page's controls.
I think you should extend the Page and on this you should do what you want.